# Restrict other user to access opened web-based InfoPath form

Tags: document-library, infopath, forms-services

May I know how to restrict other user from accessing a particular web-based InfoPath form in a document library which was open by a user? 
(Suppose that the InfoPath form need to be amend from time to time by a group of personnel)

Scenario:
User A open a web-based InfoPath form and make some modification. While User A is still editing the InfoPath form, User B came along and wanted to edit the form. So, is there any way to stop User B from opening the InfoPath form and inform him/her that the form is open by another user? (It would be nice if the message can tell User B that the document is currently open by User A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Require the item be checked out for editing in the versioning settings.

Comment: Can a web-based InfoPath form in SharePoint 2007 be checked out for editing? I thought only non-web-based InfoPath form can be checked out like a document in a document library. Do let me know if I misunderstood your answer.